# Regarding my code with Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I need a little help please. I want it to go through the array and find all destinations which is the same as the destination entered, but this finds only prints out 1. Any suggestions?
Thank You.

```
for (int x = 0; x<40;x++){
    String flight;

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Flight destination to find: ") ;
    flight = input.next();
    if (plane[x].destination.equals(flight)){
        System.out.println("Found destination! " + "\t" + "at array  " + x);
        System.out.println(plane[x].flightid + "\t" + plane[x].origin + "\t" + plane[x].destination);
        break;   
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to find one destination from the entire list?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `break` inside the `if` statement. That `break` exits the loop, which explains why you only see one flight. You also need to move the input outside of the loop, otherwise you're asking for input on every iteration of the plane loop.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Enter Flight destination to find: ") ;
String flight = input.next();

for (int x = 0; x<40;x++){
    if (plane[x].destination.equals(flight)){
        System.out.println("Found destination! " + "\t" + "at array  " + x);
        System.out.println(plane[x].flightid + "\t" + plane[x].origin + "\t" + plane[x].destination);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking the `for` loop once it finds the first destination:

```
if (plane[x].destination.equals(flight)){
                System.out.println("Found destination! " + "\t" + "at array  " + x);
                System.out.println(plane[x].flightid + "\t" + plane[x].origin + "\t" + plane[x].destination);
                break;   

}
```

so the rest of the loop is not getting executed. You need to remove this `break;` statement.

```
if (plane[x].destination.equals(flight)){
                    System.out.println("Found destination! " + "\t" + "at array  " + x);
                    System.out.println(plane[x].flightid + "\t" + plane[x].origin + "\t" + plane[x].destination);
//break;
}
```